# Java Classpath at Runtime

Tags: java, import, classpath

I am importing `import org.apache.commons.httpclient.*;` in a program, but whenever I go to run it, I have to include the JAR in the classpath. Why is this necessary? Are there any ways around this?

Comment: Where do you suppose it's going to find the classes if you don't specify where the JAR is located?

Comment: I wrote a servlet that uses an Apache package and I do not need to add the location the classpath every time it is run. So why is this case different?

Comment: How are you running the servlet?  Many servlet containers themselves use a variety of class libraries (probably using this Apache package you are referring to), so if the container consumes those libraries, they will be implicitly available because those libraries were passed to java.exe when the servlet container itself started up.

Comment: Ah, I forgot that I included that particular JAR in the /lib folder. That makes sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that it's as simple as Tomcat, by virtue of being a web server, links libraries that it (it == the java people) think that people making servlets will need and want but that would be superfluous for normal standalone java apps. Maybe one day it'll become a part of the JRE itself?

It might also be included in Tomcat's lib/ folder by default - I'm not sure.